# Create a new column with data.table that count unique values

Tags: r, data.table, calculated-columns

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |

I want to create an additional column with data table that count the unique 1s, 2s, 3s, etc and sums them up. The final dat.table would be

| ID | CountID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |

I'm trying this but does not work:

```
df[, CountID := uniqueN(df, by = ID)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### data.table

You can use `.N` for this:

```r
library(data.table)
DT[, CountID := .N, by = ID]
DT
#       ID CountID
#    <int>   <int>
# 1:     1       2
# 2:     1       2
# 3:     2       1
# 4:     3       4
# 5:     3       4
# 6:     3       4
# 7:     3       4
```

### base R

```r
DT$CountID2 <- ave(rep(1L, nrow(DT)), DT$ID, FUN = length)
```

---

Data

```r
DT <- setDT(structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), CountID = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` package

```
df1 = group_by(df, id) %>% count()
merge(df, df1)
   id n
1   1 3
2   1 3
3   1 3
4   2 1
5   3 4
6   3 4
7   3 4
8   3 4
9   4 2
10  4 2
```

**Data**

```
df = data.frame('id' = c( 1  , 1  , 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

Comment: Can I do it with data.table and the := symbol?

Comment: Not well versed with `data.table`